# Getting error while building angular code

Tags: angular

I have created angular app but getting error while executing command "**ng serve**"

Error is : The build command requires to run in an angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

I have tried to install @angular/cli, devkit core and angular packages but still I am facing the same error.

I don't know what I am missing. I have searched a lot in google but unable to resolve this error.

**Edited:** Image added.
[image]

Comment: Ensure that you are running `ng serve` in the project directory

Comment: I am writing correct command in cli and I have edited my question.

Comment: are you sure that you are in angular project directory  or folder?

Comment: Yes, I am, I have executed three command. ng new, npm install in new angular project and ng serve.

Comment: did you execute npm install and ng serve in the folder created by ng new

Comment: @lanetrotro yes

Comment: could you please post a snap of your command prompt?

Comment: @AmiVyas after creating new project by 'ng new myapp' you need to go in 'myapp' directory by 'cd myapp' then run 'ng serve'

Comment: @AnsBilal Yes, did the same thing. please read my previous comment.

Comment: share screen shot of your command prompt, try to create a new empty project and serve that

Comment: I have added image.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your directory structure where you opened the command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the terminal (commands may vary depending on your terminal):

```
[my-folder] ng new my-test
    ...
    ...
    ...
[my-folder] ls
[my-folder] . .. my-test
[my-folder] cd my-test
[my-test] ng serve
```

If at this point you get that error, then find your current Angular CLI version and update it:

```
[my-test] ng -v
[my-test] 
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.9.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0

[my-test] ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=<1.7.4>
```

With that, you'll update your Angular CLI. Pay attention to your own version. As you can see, in my case it was 1.7.4, but your's will probably be different.

Based on https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12215#issuecomment-433593036